# Xively not responding to MQTT requests

Tags: mqtt, xively

I'm trying to evaluate the xively service using MQTT.  I have created a development device and am trying to connect to it using the `mosquitto_pub` client.

If I try to open a connection to api.xively.com with no username or password I am connected successfully (CONNACK 0x00 etc).  However, if I supply my API key as a username then the connection times out (no response to the CONNECT packet).

This is the line I'm using to connect/publish:

```
mosquitto_pub.exe -h api.xively.com -u <API_KEY_HERE> -t /v2/feeds/<FEED_HERE>.csv -m 0,16.9
```

**EDIT**: and now it's working. Looks like it was something at their end.
**EDIT2**: appears to be intermittent. That's disappointing, can't be having my Things trying to connect to the cloud and having it time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend putting a Mosquitto bridge between your application and Xively. This will "buffer" and possibly hide connection issues, and it has worked rather well for me in the past year or two (although I admit to only very sporadically look at the graphs on Xively).

The bridge configuration I currently run looks like this:

`connection cosm_br
address api.cosm.com:1883
clientid xxxxx
username <API_KEY_HERE>
topic "" out 0 topicname /v2/feeds/<FEED>/datastreams/0.csv`

Setting up Mosquitto isn't difficult, but it does of course mean "more moving parts" on your side.